# Is such a question off-topic for Android SE?

Tags: discussion, question-appropriateness

This is my first question on the Meta site.

I would like to know if it's legitimate to ask a question which may be tied to development, but not have it as its main purpose to exist.

To be specific, I would like to ask from which file(s) the `pm` command of the Android shell extracts the required info when, for example, I issue the `pm list packages` command.

Is this a question that will be legitimate on the main site, or I'd rather refrain from asking it?

Comment: It doesn't really seem like an end-user concern.  Why do you ask -- curiosity?  If there's a bigger (end-user) reason, I would instead ask about *that*.

Comment: @MatthewRead No, my reason to ask this, was to know which file to read from within a Python script, in order to bypass any call to `pm`. Given this, it appears that it would be better to not ask this.

Comment: That would put the focus on development indeed – and we couldn't tell you that the *package* manager (`pm`) most likely reads from the `packages.xml` file (among others I guess). // BTW: You could always ask such things in chat :)

Comment: @Izzy That seems like a precious hint. By the way, I can't seem to log in the chat... SE is complaining about my email address. Which it already knows.

Comment: That's nothing we can do anything about. I'd suggest to use the "contact us" form on Meta.SE to get help with that.